# Freemarker: use external font

Tags: fonts, freemarker

Is it possible to use external font with Freemarker?
I tried to put `<style>` attribute in my template in order to use `@font-face` rule, but it's not working, email comes without specified font.

Content of template is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
        @font-face { font-family: Cool; src: url('font.ttf'); }
        body {
            font-family: Cool
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Email text</h1>
        <small>Very cool font</small>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then I tried to specify non-relative url in @font-face rule `src: url('http://myservername/font.ttf')` but email was also with usual font.

I tried to include external stylesheet into template as specified below:

```
...
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://myservername/style.css" />
    </head>
...
```

Content of `style.css` is:

```
@font-face { font-family: Cool; src: url('http://myservername/font.ttf'); }
body {
    font-family: Cool
}
```

When I open template in browser, all is OK:

[image: cool]

But when email comes to user - browser displays it using regular font.

[image]

Could you please help to find the problem?

Comment: It's not a FreeMarker question but a HTML+CSS+e-mail question. Also note that not all e-mail clients support custom fonts, or load resources from external URL automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really, the problem is on email client's side, it doesn't support `head` section with `style` tag.

Nice article about the topic is here: http://css-tricks.com/using-css-in-html-emails-the-real-story/